# How to show blank data until refresh for direct query in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have created one report from Direct query.
Now the requirement is when we open the report, it should show blank data until user refreshes it.
When the user refreshes it the data should be shown.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate this with some tricks:

1. Create a bookmark with no applied filters
2. Create a button and assign this bookmark as the button action
3. Filter your page to show nothing (apply some bogus filtering)
4. Save and publish report

This should make the report show nothing by default, and when the user clicks «show data» or whatever text you put on the button, the user is moved to the bookmark without any data filters, so the data is shown.

Outside of this method I can’t think of other means of showing data only when the user clicks refresh.